# How to select rows from a master sheet and display them in a subsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I hope you can help me with this as I have scoured the Internet and can't find a solution.

I have a mastersheet of parts. I want to put in quantities required against certain parts. Then I want my subsheet to populate only with parts from the master sheet that have values greater than 0. I don't want to see any other parts on the subsheet.

Example of Master Sheet:

```
PartNumber          PartName              NumberRequired
1                   Wheel                  1
2                   Bumper                 0
3                   Mirror                 1
4                   Glass Window           0
```

I want my subsheet to display only parts where the number required is greater than 0,
so the subsheet would look like this:

```
PartNumber          PartName              NumberRequired
1                   Wheel                  1
3                   Mirror                 1
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Click somewhere in your master sheet data.
2. Go to the “Data” tab, “Sort & Filter” group, and click on “Filter”.
3. In cell `C1` (the “NumberRequired” heading), click on the downward-pointing arrow.
4. In the menu that pops up, click on “0” to deselect it.  “(Blanks)” also, if applicable. 
   Now your master sheet should *look* like what you want the sub sheet to be.
5. Select all the data.
6. Type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> (semicolon).
7. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the visible data.
8. Go to (or create, if necessary) your sub sheet.
9. Click in the upper left corner and type <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the data.
10. Go back to the master sheet and click on “Filter” again, to restore the 0 rows.